# writing a function for row means

Tags: r

I am writing a function that would result in vector of row means. This function was successfully created.  When I applied this on a data frame. It results in NA.

```
row_mean<-function(x,removeNA=TRUE){
  ## determining number of rows
  nr<-nrow(x)
  ## initiate an empty vector
  means<-numeric(nr)
  for (i in 1:nr){
    means[i]<-mean(x[i,],na.rm = removeNA)
  }
  means
}
row_mean(airquality[,1:3])
```

Comment: @d.b you are right but I want to replicate it for learning purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one that works.

```
row_mean2 <- function(x, removeNA = TRUE){
    means = list()
    for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
        means[i] <- mean(as.numeric(x[i,]), na.rm = removeNA)
    }
    unlist(means)
}
row_mean2(airquality[,1:3])
```

**Edit**

Yours was very close. The reason yours did not work was that `x[i,]` was not treated as numeric. Here is a working version of your function where `x[i,]` is treated as numeric.

```
row_mean<-function(x,removeNA=TRUE){
    ## determining number of rows
    nr<-nrow(x)
    ## initiate an empty vector
    means<-numeric(nr)
    for (i in 1:nr){
        means[i]<-mean(as.numeric(x[i,]),na.rm = removeNA)
    }
    means
}
row_mean(airquality[,1:3])
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you get `NA`'s is because `x[i, ]` is still a dataframe. Taking mean on a dataframe is not defined. If you `unlist` and make it a vector it will give you the mean.

```
row_mean<-function(x,removeNA=TRUE){
    ## determining number of rows
    nr <- nrow(x)
    ## initiate an empty vector
    means <- numeric(nr)
    for (i in 1:nr){
      means[i]<-mean(unlist(x[i,]),na.rm = removeNA)
    }
     means
}

row_mean(airquality[,1:3])
# [1]  79.47  54.00  57.87 114.17  14.30  21.45 110.20  43.93  15.70 101.30
# [11]   6.95  93.90 103.40  99.63  32.07 119.83 117.67  34.13 121.17  21.57
#...
```

Comment: I got the intuition. Thanks